# Set 'texi2dvi' for 'R CMD Rd2pdf'

Tags: r, documentation, package, texinfo

My `texi2dvi` is apparently in a place where `R CMD Rd2pdf` doesn't expect it.  Mine is at `/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi`, and it's being looked for at `/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi`:

```
[KenMacBook:~/git] % \R CMD Rd2pdf missing
Hmm ... looks like a package
Converting Rd files to LaTeX 
Creating pdf output from LaTeX ...
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.
Messages:
sh: /usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi: No such file or directory
Output:

Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.
Messages:
sh: /usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi: No such file or directory
Output:

Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
```

I can work around this by running `R_TEXI2DVICMD=/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi R CMD Rd2pdf`, and then the docs are built correctly.

I'd like to put that setting in my `.Rprofile` so that things like RStudio (which won't read my `.zshrc`) and other random R sessions will see the setting.  But neither of the following seems to have any effect in my `.Rprofile`:

```
Sys.setenv(R_TEXI2DVICMD='/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi')
options(texi2dvi='/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi')
```

I'm guessing `.Rprofile` doesn't get read by `R CMD` commands, is that correct?  Is there an appropriate place to put my settings?

**UPDATE:**

Since Dirk doubts my doubting of `.RProfile` for affecting `R CMD Rd2pdf` :-), here's my evidence:

```
[KenMacBook:~/git] % tail -n2 ~/.Rprofile
Sys.setenv(TEXI2DVI='/no/where')
cat("End of RProfile\n")

[KenMacBook:~/git] % Rscript -e '2+2'    
End of RProfile
[1] 4

[KenMacBook:~/git] % R CMD Rd2pdf missing
Hmm ... looks like a package
Converting Rd files to LaTeX 
Creating pdf output from LaTeX ...
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.
Messages:
sh: /usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi: No such file or directory
Output:

Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.
Messages:
sh: /usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi: No such file or directory
Output:

Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
```

Notice that the file's settings are respected in a normal R session, but setting `TEXI2DVI` has no effect here.

Answer (score 1):

That seems wrong as `/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi` should be in the `$PATH`. 
I have

```
edd@max:~$ grep texi2dvi /etc/R/Renviron
## used for options("texi2dvi")
R_TEXI2DVICMD=${R_TEXI2DVICMD-${TEXI2DVI-'/usr/bin/texi2dvi'}}
edd@max:~$
```

Note that if you want to set the `TEXI2DVI` environment variable, you probably have to do start *before* you start R -- think `~/.bash_profile`

Here is an example *explicitly setting `TEXI2DVI`*:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ TEXI2DVI=/no/where R CMD Rd2pdf Rcpp-package.Rd 
Converting Rd files to LaTeX ...
  Rcpp-package.Rd
Creating pdf output from LaTeX ...
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.
Messages:
sh: 1: /no/where: not found
Output:

Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.
Messages:
sh: 1: /no/where: not found
Output:

Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
edd@max:/tmp$
```

As you can see, it is respected.

*Edit:* Also let's not forget `Renviron` and `Renviron.site` so you have plenty of choices so set his.

*Edit 2:* As you seem to doubt `~/.Rprofile`:

```
edd@max:~$ tail -1 .Rprofile
cat("End of .Rprofile\n")
edd@max:~$ Rscript -e '2+2'
End of .Rprofile
[1] 4
edd@max:~$
```

Comment: Hmm - it looks like my `/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/etc/Renviron` file (I'm on a Mac, R is installed using Homebrew) contains `R_TEXI2DVICMD=${R_TEXI2DVICMD-${TEXI2DVI-'/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi'}}`.

Comment: Yes these things get diagnosed "and written down" during configuration and build.  You could just edit that file (and the loose the change on thenext upgrade).  Setting a (user-local or system-wide) environment variable may better.

Comment: I don't think I have an opportunity to set `R_TEXI2DVICMD` or `TEXI2DVI` before R is launched, unless I set it in `/etc/launchd.conf` or something (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: Why? Also see my edit: R itself gives you two files in its `etc/` and your `$HOME`.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot about `Renviron.site`, that's probably a good place to set it.

Comment: What are the 2 files in `$HOME`?  Neither `.Rprofile` nor `.Renviron` seems to have any effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96600/discussion-between-ken-williams-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).

Comment: I realize I can edit my `.Rprofile` to affect an R session.  What I claim (see my original question) is that it doesn't affect `R CMD Rd2pdf` in any helpful way.  I'll edit my question to make this more explicit.

Comment: It will affect _new_ sessions and as such will effect the _next time_ you lauch `R CMD foo` for various `foo` subcommands supported by R.  It will affect the _current_ section because these files are read at startup.

Comment: And recall that I recommended from the start that you alter your `bash` or whatever settings.  If OS X forbids that, then, well, go complain to Cupertino because this no longer is the Unix was.  But you can _always_ craft your own shell script with its own settings.   This thread has gotten too long, so I will now excuse myself.

Comment: Ok, looks like `R CMD ...` is indeed skipping this so if I were you I'd just edit the main `Renviron` file which is clearly wrong for your system.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: And as for your edit above, **I never said that `Sys.setenv("somekey"="somevalue")` would work**. You have to set these **before** R starts to affect the **current** process from which you run subcommands.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'd like to condense this info into only the relevant parts for the question, so that I have something to point co-workers & other Homebrew users at.  I'm happy to do that, but if you'd like to instead, please feel free.

Comment: It's a bug in homebrew and the resulting R installation. No more, no less. Have it fixed there are you're good.

Comment: Ya great.  In the meantime I'll write up something here to work around it.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue,   `Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.` and `/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi: makeindex failed`. `/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi: line 281: makeindex: command not found`.
I'm getting this during the `R CMD check`, but I could be able to reproduce the case by doing:  `R CMD Rd2pdf package_name --no-clean`.
My current `$PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and figured out how to fix it - I think it has something to do with a previous installation of macports interfering with the path when R has been installed using brew (assuming you're on OSX).

Run the following in terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Then go Apple > Force Quit > Finder > Relaunch. You'll now be able to see hidden files.

In your user directory there may be a file named .profile, in this file I commented out the line (i.e. put a # in front of it, as shown).

```
#export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Then navigate to your R.home() (get this by running R.home() in R)

```
R.home()
[1] "/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.4_1/R.framework/Resources"
```

And modify the following line in Renviron

```
R_TEXI2DVICMD=${R_TEXI2DVICMD-${TEXI2DVI-'/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi'}}
```

This fixed it for me.

To put finder back to usual run

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE`

in the terminal and relaunch it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The back-and-forth with Dirk produced some solutions, but they're pretty buried, so I summarize them here.

### Diagnosis: `etc/Renviron` contains stale info.

My `/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/etc/Renviron` file (installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)) contains this line:

```
R_TEXI2DVICMD=${R_TEXI2DVICMD-${TEXI2DVI-'/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi'}}
```

That's a remnant of someone (possibly me, possibly Homebrew's R package creator) who installed [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/) in the default location, and then that path got frozen in time in the `Renviron` file.  My `texi2dvi` is now at `/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi`, so this value needs to be overridden somehow.

### 1) `$HOME/.Rprofile` and `$HOME/.Renviron` won't help.

They don't take effect soon enough for R to notice them.  R sets `options("texi2dvi")` based on the environment it sees at startup,

```
% tail -n2 ~/.Rprofile
Sys.setenv(TEXI2DVI='/no/where')
options(texi2dvi='/no/where/else')

% cat ~/.Renviron
TEXI2DVI=/no/where/at/all

% R CMD Rd2pdf myPackageDirectory   # Still no joy
Hmm ... looks like a package
Converting Rd files to LaTeX 
Creating pdf output from LaTeX ...
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.
Messages:
sh: /usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi: No such file or directory
...
```

See "[Initialization at Start of an R Session](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html)" for more info about startup files, though as shown above, the information in that document about overriding `R_HOME/etc/Renviron` is either incorrect or incomplete for this situation.  Perhaps it should be amended in the section about `R_CHECK_ENVIRON` and `R_BUILD_ENVIRON` to also include something about `R CMD RD2*`, but I'm not sure whether that's what's going on, I only know this isn't a solution.

### 2) `$HOME/.zshrc` (and friends) won't help.

On OS X, your shell startup file is not consulted when you launch GUI apps.  You could [use `defaults write` or `launchctl setenv`](http://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1842) to change the `TEXI2DVI` variable so that it's set when R launches, but you'd also have to stick it in your shell startup file for processes *not* started by `launchd`, which is icky.  I also [version my dotfiles](https://github.com/kenahoo/dotfiles), and I don't like sticking this bit of configuration in the `launchctl` ether where I can't easily remember it's there.  But `launchctl` is presumably one solution to this.

### 3) `etc/Renviron.site` won't help.

This one is surprising - I expected it to work:

```
% cat /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/etc/Renviron.site
R_TEXI2DVICMD=/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi
TEXI2DVI=/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi

% \R CMD Rd2pdf myPackageDirectory
Hmm ... looks like a package
Converting Rd files to LaTeX 
Creating pdf output from LaTeX ...
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.
Messages:
sh: /usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi: No such file or directory
```

So `Renviron.site`'s settings aren't taking effect here.  I'm getting impatient, so I didn't try to diagnose why.

### 3) Editing `etc/Renviron` as a last resort

So this finally works:

```
% grep TEXI2DVI /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/etc/Renviron 
TEXI2DVI=/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi  ## Added by Ken
R_TEXI2DVICMD=${R_TEXI2DVICMD-${TEXI2DVI-'/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi'}}
```

I don't like it much, because I'll lose those settings next time I upgrade R.  And R's documentation specifically says ["do not change ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron’ itself"](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html).  But at least it works.